# Decimal to Binary Conversion in C

Tags: c, function, search, binary, decimal

Implement the inspect_bits function that checks if given number contains 2 or more consecutive ones in its binary representation. If it does, the function should return 1. Otherwise, it should return 0.

For example, inspect_bits(13) should return 1 as it contains 2 consecutive ones in its binary representation (1101).

The program is working for certain numbers, 13 in this case, and a few others, however, the program is not working for '8','10' and for some other numbers.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int inspect_bits(unsigned int number)
{
    int arr[32];
    int i=0,temp,c=0;;

    while(number > 0)
    {
        arr[i] = number%2;
        number = number/2;
        i++;
    }
    for (int j=i-1; j>=0; j--)
    {
        temp = arr[j];
            for (int k=j+1; k>0; k--)
            {
                if (temp==arr[k])
                c++;
            }
    }
    if (c != 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

#ifndef RunTests
int main ()
{
    printf("%d", inspect_bits(13));
}
#endif
```

Comment: What is it `return`ing for `8` and `10`?

Comment: Hint: under what conditions is `c` set to a non-zero value, and under what conditions is it set to zero?

Comment: I'd inspect the bits directly by using the `&` and possibly the `<<` or `>>` operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks *way* too complicated, as an algorithm implementation and to debug. This is simpler:

```
int inspect_bits(unsigned int number)
{
   while (number)
   {
      if ((number & 3) == 3)
          return 1;
      number >>= 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The loop tests the last two bits of `number` against 3, which is `00000011` in binary. If this matches, then there were (at least!) two consecutive bits in `number`. If not, the bits in `number` are shifted to the right and tested again. The loop can stop when `number` reaches 0 -- technically even `while (number > 2)` as only values higher than 2 have more than two consecutive bits.

Comment: Maybe you can add that `3` in decimal is `11` in binary.

Comment: It WORKED! Can you explain this?

Answer (score 3):

To determine whether the unsigned integer `n` has two adjacent bits set, it is enough to test:

```
(n & (n >> 1)) != 0
```

There `n >> 1` is the number `n` shifted one bit to the right, which is the same as an integer division by 2. You can visualize this method by numbering the bits:

```
n            7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
n >> 1         7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

The bitwise and (`&`) is a binary operator. Its result will have a bit set if both operands have the respective bit set. In the expression above, it will have bit 0 set if `n` has both bit 0 and 1 set; it will have bit 1 set if `n` has both bit 1 and 2 set and so on. It will have no bits set (and therefore be zero) if no two adjacent bits of `n` are set.